# Add Ruby code into JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, slim-lang

I am working with Ruby on Rails, JavaScript and Simple Form and I have a problem adding Ruby code into a function in JavaScript.

My source code is:

```
$('#add_taxo').on('click',function() {
    document.getElementById('okok').innerHTML += '<li class="list-group-item"> <%= taxonomies_select_tag( 'statistic[taxonomy]', Folders::Taxonomy, Folders::Taxonomy::TAXONOMY_KEY, level: 3, path: 'folders/taxonomies', include_blank: true, class: 'required form-control test_taxo')%> </li>';
    alert("lklk"); 
});
```

This code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use ruby code through the view/*.js/coffee.erb files via ajax.  You can't use ruby in plain js/coffeescript files.  If you need to pass data from the controller to the js side, then pass them through hidden field tags in your view through data attributes.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806146/add-ruby-code-into-javascript-code/45808043#45808043

Comment: This is not duplicate code.  That example does not explain that the code in context, needs to handled through an ajax response within the 'views/*js.erb', and not the assets.

Answer (score 0):

Try *escaping the javascript* in the ruby code, like this:

```
document.getElementById('okok').innerHTML += '<li class="list-group-item"> <%= j(taxonomies_select_tag( 'statistic[taxonomy]', Folders::Taxonomy, Folders::Taxonomy::TAXONOMY_KEY, level: 3, path: 'folders/taxonomies', include_blank: true, class: 'required form-control test_taxo'))%> </li>';
```

You can use either `escape_javascript(...)` or `j(...)` (as in the example).

Comment: @youssefhassoun Do you get any errors on either server logs or browser console?

Answer (score 0):

make sure extension is `.js.erb` and it's part of views folder.

If you want to do it through plain js then pass those variables through `html`, for eg: hidden fields, html tag properties.